# Insert With Date_Format Function Using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

My SQL statement using PHP doesn't insert the `date_format` MySQL function that I would like to use in order to show the current date-time in the format of "Friday, 12/20/2013 - 12:31 PM PST". Rather it inserts '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
  $command = "insert into $table_name
                 values('','".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."',              
                 date_format(now(), '%W, %m/%d/%Y - %h:%i %p PST'),                      
                 '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['entry'])."');";
```

Comment: While inserting date into mysql DB you can insert date in Y-m-d H:i:s date format as mysql accepts that date format only. In order to show date in required format you can do as follows:

date("<your format>",strtotime(<variable which fetches date from DB>));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to save date to a column with either `datetime` datatype or `time_stamp`. Change the column datatype to string rather.

But I would suggest you to keep the datatype to `datetime` and fetch date formatted

```
"INSERT INTO $table_name VALUES( '" .date("Y-m-d H:i:s"). "' )";
```

and while selecting the date from this table fetch it like

```
"SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%W, %m/%d/%Y - %h:%i %p PST') AS fDate FROM $table_name";
```